# Использование рекурсии в создание 3 массива из 2 существующих

Tags: python, массивы, рекурсия

Всем доброго времени суток! У меня есть задача:
    Даны 2 массива целых чисел х1,...,хn, y1,...,yn. Получить новый массив по cледующему правилу:   zi = (xi+yi)/yi.

Как выполнить задачу без  рекурсии я представляю, а вот как втулить сюда рекурсию - нет! Пожалуйста, кто разбирается, дайте идею!

Comment: срезами... что-то в духе `return {(x[0]+y[0]/y[0])} + func(x.remove(0),y.remove(0))` питона не знаю чисто как идею или что-то такое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def CreateArray(x, y, z=None):
    if z is None:
        z = []
    try:
        z.append(x.pop(0) / y.pop(0) + 1)
        return CreateArray(x, y, z)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass  # обработка деления на 0
    except IndexError:
        return z

print(CreateArray([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))  # [1.25, 1.4, 1.5]
```

Comment: плохая идея делать значение по умолчанию таким образом `z=[]`. Вызовите два раза подряд вашу функцию и поймете почему. Если очень нужно сделать значение по умолчанию, то делайте так: `z=None` и первой строкой в теле `if z is None: z = []`

Comment: Большое вам спасибо1